# Download softwares along with dependancy

Tags: apt, offline, xen

I am trying to download xen hypervisor so that when ever Internet isn't available I can install it. I am using this:

```
sudo apt-get download xen-hypervisor-4.1-i386
```

This will create a `.deb file`, but when I am going to install it, it shows me lots of dependencies errors. However, when I am using:

```
sudo apt-get install xen-hypervisor-4.1-i386
```

It will work perfectly. So is there is any way to download software will all dependency packages??

Answer (score 1):

What about using install with a -d option (download-only)?

i.e.

```
sudo apt-get install -d xen-hypervisor-4.1-i386
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to download your package with all dependency......

`sudo apt-get install xen-hypervisor-4.1-i386` this command will search and download this package with all dependency. You can see it in the terminal when it promote your permission to download and proceed with installation.

If you wanna make this package & dependency available for off-line installation then simply do this.

`sudo apt-get clean` to clean previous downloaded cache. When you download or install a package from **terminal/software center**, both download files to a system folder `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

`sudo apt-get clean` to clean previous downloaded cache.

Simply install your package from terminal or software center and collect all `.deb` from this folder and preserve it in another location.

You are done. Next time when you want to install, then simply follow this instruction

Open up a terminal and type

`cd ~/Desktop/offline` i am assuming that you copy thoese `.deb` to this folder. It can be any where. Just go to that directory with terminal.

then type `sudo dpkg -i *.*deb` if the folder contain more than one `.deb`. It will install this package with all downloded dependency.

If dependency problem still occurs during install then do the following

`sudo apt-get -f install` it will fix the problem by downloading and installing the desire package. Please do a `sudo apt-get clean` before installing new package if you wanna keep it for off-line install.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the command you used to download the file.

1. CTRL+ALT+T (to open Terminal).
2. `sudo apt-get install wget`.
3. `wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/x/xen/xen-hypervisor-4.1-i386_4.1.3~rc1+hg-20120614.a9c0a89c08f2-4_i386.deb`.

I hope that helps

Comment: Does it help to resolve dependency problem of this following package?

Answer (score 0):

The `apt-get install` command automatically pulls in dependencies from Ubuntu repository, allowing you to easily install packages you need.

Installing a single .deb file **does not automatically pull in dependencies**, you need to install them manually too.

That's why `apt-get install` is the preferred way of installing software in Ubuntu, as opposed to dealing with single .deb files.

---

If you want to dowload a .deb package from repository along with it's all dependencies, this will be a really hard task. The point is that these dependencies also have dependencies, which also have dependencies... and it would probably turn out that you need to download 1000 packages to fully satisfy all dependencies.

Therefore, if using `sudo apt-get install` is not satisfying you, I suggest you to provide more details on what you want to **achieve** by downloading this package with it dependencies, so you could get detailed help in that matter.

And I repeat, if you simply want to install this package, do not bother dealing with single .deb files. Using `apt-get install` will deal with dependencies for you automatically.